# I am trying to use the react-navigation, and getting this error

Tags: react-native

[image]

I am trying to use the react-navigation, and getting this 
**ERROR:**

> 17:04
>   warn Package react-native-gesture-handler has been ignored because it contains invalid configuration. Reason: Cannot find module 'react-native-gesture-handler\package.json'
>   Require stack:
>   - E:\ReactNativeProject\stackNavigationTesting\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\config\resolveNodeModuleDir.js
>   - E:\ReactNativeProject\stackNavigationTesting\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\releaseChecker\index.js
>   - E:\ReactNativeProject\stackNavigationTesting\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\server\runServer.js
>   - E:\ReactNativeProject\stackNavigationTesting\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\server\server.js
>   - E:\ReactNativeProject\stackNavigationTesting\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\index.js
>   - E:\ReactNativeProject\stackNavigationTesting\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js
>   - E:\ReactNativeProject\stackNavigationTesting\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\cli.js

Answer (score 0):

This error is because you havent installed [`react-native-gesture-handler`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-gesture-handler)

You can use `npm install react-native-gesture-handler`

After installation you will be free from this error

Thanks

Comment: yeah I followed the documentation and installed everything( react-native-gesture-handler, react-native-reanimated, react-native-screens and react-native-safe-area-context) still getting this

Comment: have you linked the package using this command
react-native link react-native-gesture-handler

Comment: yeah... though I use expo.

Comment: I am new in React-Native

Comment: are you running on android or IOS

Comment: I am trying to run it on Android

Comment: and you are getting this error while installing the react-navigation or by running your application ?

Comment: try to uninstall both the package and then try again ,I hope then it will work because it seems that its some installation problem

Comment: check react native gesture handler doc for android https://software-mansion.github.io/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: @piyalidey Please use the edit link under the *Question* to add all the information provided in replies in comments to the question. Only then can people properly assess the problem. Most won't continue to this long set of comments...

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using this command:

```
npm install
```

and try it again